# Angular 5 data request

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5

I've build an application with Angular 5 and Java Spring Boot.

I currently have the problem that I can't take the received data out of my data service in Angular.

This is my data service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getClasses(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('//localhost:8080/classes');
  }
}
```

This is the component where I want to put the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-classes',
  templateUrl: './classes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./classes.component.css']
})
export class ClassesComponent implements OnInit {

  classes: Array<any>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClasses();
  }

  getClasses(): void {
    this.dataService.getClasses().subscribe(data => {this.classes = data});
  }
}
```

This is what I get from console.log(data):

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {version: null, id: 1, name: "3AHIT"}
1: {version: null, id: 2, name: "4AHIT"}
2: {version: null, id: 3, name: "5AHIT"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And this from console.log(this.classes):

```
undefined
```

I used this tutorial for my application: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/04/basic-crud-angular-and-spring-boot

I haven't found anything that helped me and I hope that somebody can help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you calling `console.log(this.classes)`?

Comment: I put it inside the ngOnInit() below this.getClasses()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getClasses()` method is an `async` function, so if you try to `console.log(this.classes)` in your `ngOnInit`, right after calling `this.getClasses()` it will return `undefined` because your `console.log` gets fired before your call to backend gets resolved.

So if you want to check that the value of you `classes` variable has been updated you should do that in the `subscribe` of your method. Somehting like this:

```
getClasses(): void {
    this.dataService.getClasses().subscribe(data => {
    this.classes = data;
    console.log(this.classes);
   });
}
```

This way you make sure you log your variable once the call to your backend has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The data are retreived inside your subscription. IE:

```
        this.dataService.getClasses().subscribe(data => {
        this.classes = data;
        console.log(this.classes); // <--- this will log your data
        //call a function with this.classes for exemple here
        });
```

If you are using `this.classes` outside the result of the subscription it will be undefined since the request has not completed

Comment: But what can I do that my this.classes is filled with the data I want?

Comment: What do you mean, 'what can I do'? You want the data - the answer provides it, do what you need to do with it.